# How would you verify that a certain css element on a page is a certain image with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, automated-tests

I have a page that I want to check with selenium that uses a certain background image for one element. I want to ensure that this image still exists on the page connected to the element. How would I do this with selenium. If this changes anything I am using browsermob.com to do the testing once I get it running through selenium ide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asserting the background image of a page with selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799173/asserting-the-background-image-of-a-page-with-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

Well aside from the suggested things on the almos duplicate issue... You could check if the property of your body element is set to the image.

By if getAttribute returns a valid value or not. Like:

```
new Wait()
    {

        public boolean until()
        {
            return selenium.getAttribute("ElementLocator")
                + "@class").equals("active");
        }
    }.wait("The menu item did not get active.",
        defaultTimeOutValue);
```

This will wait for the attribute @class to have the value "active".

Or simply use an If statement after you are sure that the page got loaded.

Hope this helps,
Cheers,
Gergely.